# How to set circle radius based on % of a value?

Tags: javascript

Currently I have circles drawn on a map and I set the radius doing:

```
radius: density * (1 - 0.65)
```

That works somehow as it avoids getting too big since that `density` value could be huge. Yet everything changes when we have little `density` value as the circles gets too small.

**UPDATE**

One idea could be, since these circles are a bunch of data on the map but we also have the total density called `globalDensity` which gives us the sum of all densities, maybe there is a way to get a % of that?

**UPDATE TWO**

Actually that idea is not possible since the total is calculated after all circles have been placed on the map.

**UPDATE THREE**

We have plenty of different circles on a map with dynamic density values, these various from a min of `zero` to a max of `X number`

When I do `radius: density * (1 - 0.65)` works well when sizing the `big values` but doesn't work when we have let's say, 1 as density
    value

At some point after the loop, I calculate also ALL densities but unfortunately that happens after the loop e.g. after I push all densities in an array and I do the sum, so it's too late to use that as a maxValue to do the calculation.

A comment below the question has suggested to use a `minValue` and a `maxValue` which makes sense but I'm not sure how to then calculate the % based on that, I tried the following but I'm doing it wrong as the result is a **Huge** circle.

```
var minRadius = 1000;

var maxRadius = density;

var percentage = maxRadius * (1 - 0.40);

var radius = minRadius + percentage * (maxRadius -minRadius).toFixed(0);
```

Comment: You can always define the formula as `minRadius + percentage * (maxRadius - minRadius)`.

Comment: @t.niese check the updated answer, maybe that's an idea? But I'm not sure how would I do that. Any example on an answer you could place please?

Comment: `also have the total density called globalDensity` what does this mean? Is that the maximum density, of all given densities, is it the sum of all? And if it is the sum of all, why don't you calculate the maximum density, and use that to calculate the percentage value?

Comment: @t.niese yes indeed, it is the sum of all. But unfortunately I can't, because I calculate that sum after the loop where I insert the circles, so the radius is already set by that time. Should remove the that bit from the question, or rather update it by specifying that idea isn't valid. tried this tho, but circles gets huge on first load                     `var minRadius = positive - 40;
                    var maxRadius = positive
                    var percentage = positive * (1 - 0.65); 
                    var radius = minRadius + percentage * (maxRadius - minRadius);`

Comment: One thing to improve that question: show a minimal sample of what you are doing. Certainly you can refactor it so that you know the extents of your data before setting this radius, perform two loops if necessary. But without showing anything to us, we can't really be helpful to you, and your question to us.

Comment: @Kaiido I agree, and I am willing to improve the question, if anyone asks as you just did. I have updated the question, let me know if you want to add anything else or if that it's fine. Thanks

Comment: @Kaiido yeah I wanted to avoid double looping :(

Comment: If you don't know the min and max value, then you need to do a double loop there is no way around that.

Comment: `agree, and I am willing to improve the question, if anyone asks as you just did. I have updated the question, let me know if you want to add anything else or if that it's fine.` you should read your question initially, and think about if someone not knowing your project has all information. Everyone spending time here does this in their spare time. And the time spent to clearify a vague question is time missing that could help someone else. (And no I didn't downvote)

Comment: @t.niese sure but we sometime think something is clear unless someone tell us the opposite. We are not always sure what it's clear for us it's clear to anyone else too. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over data is fast, don't worry about it.

One may think that with big data it would be better to avoid looping twice, but actually given how JIT nowadays does an awesome job at optimizing, having two loops performing a single action is often faster than having a single one doing two things.

So simply do a first pass over your data to get the extents:

```
const data = [ ...
const extents = data.reduce( (extents, datum) => {
  const value = datum.value;
  extents.min = Math.min( extents.min, value );
  extents.max = Math.max( extents.max, value );
  return extents;
}, { min: Infinity, max: -Infinity } );
```

Now, you need to define the `minRadius` and `maxRadius` values to the visual extents you want. (I guess it will be in pixels).

```
const minRadius = 5; // circles can't be smaller than that
const maxRadius = 30; // circles can't be bigger than that
```

Finally you can set your circles radii based on these extents:

```
const valDistance = extents.max - extents.min;
const radiusDistance = maxRadius - minRadius;
data.forEach( datum => {
  datum.radius = (datum.value - extents.min) / valDistance * radiusDistance + minRadius;
} );
```

```js
const data = Array.from({ length: 20 }, () => ({
  value: Math.random() * 300 - 150
}));
const extents = data.reduce((extents, datum) => {
  const value = datum.value;
  extents.min = Math.min(extents.min, value);
  extents.max = Math.max(extents.max, value);
  return extents;
}, { min: Infinity, max: -Infinity });
const minRadius = 5; // circles can't be smaller than that
const maxRadius = 30; // circles can't be bigger than that

const valDistance = extents.max - extents.min;
const radiusDistance = maxRadius - minRadius;
data.forEach(datum => {
  datum.radius = (datum.value - extents.min) / valDistance * radiusDistance + minRadius;
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, will try to apply your logic.